# Efficient lookup for objects in a list with large arrays as member elements

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list

Hi I have a class as following

```
class State
{
    int[] some_array;
    //some other members
}
```

Now I need to compare whether two State objects are same or not. I define two states same if **they have the same `some_array`** ***irrespective of other members of the object***.

Now I have a list of thousands of State objects in it. How can I efficiently take a state and find out another similar state is present in the list by lookup?

I can compare the `some_array` array of every state element in the list with the given state object. But this will take so many computation O(N*size of some_array). How can I do this with minimal computation?

Note: All except one array entitlements will be almost same in each case. So, the look up can go to very deep in the array.

Comment: Are two `some_array` members considered equal if they have the same items only, or do they have to have the same items in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but creating a hash of the contents in your array sounds like a good solution to me. That way you can just compare the hashes instead of iterating the whole array and comparing every individual value.

Comment: Indeed. Simply override `GetHashCode` and make it return a hash for the array, and implement `Equals` so that it checks the internal array for equality. Then a simple `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` would do the rest.

Comment: Not necessarily.  GetHashCode() has a VERY specific use in the .Net framework.  Be sure the semantics of equality are compatible between this domain specific definition and the .NET assumption (that the hash code can be used for Dictionary / HashSet membership).

Comment: If you are redefining `object.Equals`, it makes sense to redefine `GetHashCode`.  If it makes sense to implement this by overriding `Equals`, then you should have no issue implementing `GetHashCode` (as long as you follow the rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).  If it doesn't, and this is just a certain comparison you're doing, then you might try to hash another way, but without overriding `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Hi what if I made a string of the array elements while building the states and store them as a member in the State class? then i will have to compare the strings only.  will it be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming order matters, your algorithm is O(N) *worst case*.  If values tend to be different for different states, the test will generally fail very early while comparing elements of two candidates.  If the data were completely random, the performance to compare two states to each other would approach O(1)... the very first array elements would differ most of the time, odds of first two being identical would be much smaller, etc.  If you know something about the structure of the data in the array (e.g. maybe most likely to differ at the end?) you can exploit that.  Of course of the array lengths can be different, check that before anything else.

If the array is not going to change after initialization, you can precalculate a hash of the array elements.  However, unless my first statement does not apply (you will generally get far into the array before detecting a difference), a hash may not be the best option.

Comment: Yes order matters. Actually all except one array elemements will be almost same in each case. So the look up can go to very deep in the array.